# IntegrityError while trying to send a notification with django-notifications

Tags: python, django, django-notification

I've installed [`django-notifications`](https://github.com/brantyoung/django-notifications) via pip, added the app to my `INSTALLED_APPS`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    ...
    'notifications',
    ...
)
```

Updated my URLConf:

```
import notifications

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ...
    ('^inbox/notifications/', include(notifications.urls), namespace='notifications'),
    ...
)
```

Since I have `south` installed, I migrate the schema:

```
$ python manage.py migrate notifications
...
...

$ python manage.py migrate --list

 notifications
  (*) 0001_initial
  (*) 0002_auto__add_field_notification_data
  (*) 0003_auto__add_field_notification_unread
  (*) 0004_convert_readed_to_unread
  (*) 0005_auto__del_field_notification_readed
  (*) 0006_auto__add_field_notification_level

 ...
```

Now, I'm trying to manually create a notification via Django shell but I'm getting an `IntegrityError`:

```
[1]: from django.contrib.auth.models import User

[2]: from notifications import notify

[3]: recipient = User.objects.get(username="admin")

[4]: sender = User.objects.get(username="guest")

[5]: notify.send(sender, verb='A test', recipient=recipient)
...
...
...
IntegrityError: (1452, 'Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`myapp`.`notifications_notification`, CONSTRAINT `recipient_id_refs_id_5c79cb54` FOREIGN KEY (`recipient_id`) REFERENCES `auth_user` (`id`))')
```

What's going on? Both, `recipient` and `sender` belong to `auth_user` table. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: the first argument should be the recipient, use `actor=sender` or re order arguments `notify.send(recipient, sender, verb='A test')`

Comment: @AamirAdnan that's not working either. I f a try `notify.send(recipient, actor=sender, verb='A test')` then I get a `KeyError "recipient"`. If I use `notify.send(recipient, sender, verb='A test')` I get `TypeError: send() takes exactly 2 arguments (4 given)`

Comment: try this `notify.send(recipient=recipient, sender=sender, verb='A test')` this should work.

Comment: @AamirAdnan with that I get the IntegrityError again. Thanks, it seems the problem is somewhere else

Comment: @AamirAdnan nope, it is expecting recipient keyword so I'm getting KeyError "recipient"

Comment: @AamirAdnan for some reason, it is working in my home laptop but not in my work PC

Comment: Just un-install the django-notifications package and re-install it on your work pc. That's the advice I can give at this moment.

Comment: Integrity errors are usually database-related in my experience, which might explain why the code itself works on a different setup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the problem. For some reason `south` was using InnoDB storage engine as a default while all my tables have MyISAM as a default. This is how I fixed it:

1. Drop table `notifications_notification`
2. Delete all entries of `notifications` on `south_migrationhistory` table so you can migrate `notifications` again later
3. Add [`STORAGE_ENGINE`](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/settings.html#mysql-storage-engine) to my database settings:

   ```
   DATABASES = {
       'default': {
           'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
           'NAME': 'database',       
           'USER': 'user',           
           'PASSWORD': 'pass',       
           'HOST': '',               
           'PORT': '',               
           'STORAGE_ENGINE': 'MyISAM',
       }
   }
   ```
4. Finally, migrate `notifications` again:

   ```
   $ python manage.py migrate notifications
   ```